# curl: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, curl, openssl

I'm trying to connect from one server (A) in AWS to another server (B) in AWS with Tomcat 7 + SSL.

Server A:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- OpenSSL 1.0.1f

Server B:

- Ubuntu 13.04
- Tomcat 7
- OpenSSL 1.0.1c
- SSL Certificate

I'm trying the following command in server A:

```
curl https://Server.B -v
```

And I get the following exception:

```
* Connection #0 to host test.salespredict.com left intact
yakirm@ip-10-214-10-178:~$ curl https://Server.B.com -v
* Rebuilt URL to: https://Server.B.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.245.81.*...
* Connected to Server.B.com (54.245.81.*) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to Server.B.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to Server.B.com:443
```

I tried to check with OpenSSL

```
openssl s_client -connect Server.B.Address:443
```

I get the following result:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140284858304160:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

If I'm trying to connect from my own computer (OS X Mavericks), the curl success but the openssl command return the same.

*BTW*

If I'm trying:

```
curl https://Server.B -v -ssl3
```

It's work from Server A, but I don't want to specify the SSL protocol.

**Edit**

Server B - Tomcat Configuration:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
                   enableLookups="true" maxThreads="200" port="443" keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/Path/Path_keystore" keystorePass="******" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" 
                   secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Comment: Just note that "-ssl3" is not equal to "--sslv3" but the same as -s -s -l -3 ...

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between setting [--sslv3](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-3) and not setting it is, that the client will not announce support for versions higher than SSL3.0 in the initial ClientHello message. Usually client and server agree on a version supported by both sides, so that it is correct for the client to announce the best SSL version it supports.

It looks like that in your case your are confronted with a situation, where the server (or some middlebox) is not only unable to speak newer TLS versions but which is also unable to deal with SSL 3.0 properly, because it croaks if the client announces support for newer versions. Since the server software itself does not look old you have either a really strange server setup or some middlebox (i.e. load balancer, firewall...) which is unable to deal with proper TLS.

More information might be possible if you post more information about the server. Also you might check the server against [SSLLabs](http://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

EDIT: It looks like the server supports TLS1.* but simply disconnects when the client offers an 
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA cipher. Using `openssl s_client -cipher 'ALL:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'` works as does `curl --ciphers 'ALL:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'`. I assume this is a problem on the server side - maybe you have configured ciphers which in reality are not supported by the SSL implementation in tomcat (which is not OpenSSL, because Java has its own implementation) and Java croaks when it tries to use them.

Comment: I added the Tomcat configuration (Support TLS)...
Can you tell me what more information you would like to get?
Just reminding you that the server in AWS...

Comment: Have you tried to check the server against ssllabs, like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I got 100 in certificate, 90 in Protocol Support, 40 in key exchange and 60 in Cipher Strength (will fix it in the next renewal...).
In the Handshake Simulation I got almost all of them Succeed... (most android failed)...

Comment: Would it be a problem to just publish the name of the site here? It is really hard to debug a problem with only vague information: the percent ratings say nothing about the problems it detected on the site.

Comment: See edit - I think this is a misconfiguration on the servers end or a bug in Java.